# Replace data after "Submit" button

Tags: php, html

Would like to know how can I display a new set of data after a "Submit" button. What I am trying to do is if a page is loaded at the start, it will display all the data at default until a value in the dropdown box is selected. For example, if the user selects "Available" in the dropdown box and clicks on submit, the page will replace all data with only the "Available" ones.

HTML

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <select name="status" id="status" class="formcontrol">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>List</option>
      <option value="All">All</option>
      <option value="Available">Available</option>
      <option value="Rented">Rented</option>
      <option value="Overdue">Overdue</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="submit6" name="submit6" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP

```php
if (isset($_POST["submit6"])) {
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {   
      if ($_POST["status"] == "Available") {}
   }
}
```

As of right now, the "All" data is unable to be replaced by the "Available" data. In short to say, the "all" data is still displayed after the "Submit" button.

Comment: What does "a new set of data" mean? What would happen if you add any output instead of `//display only "Available" data`?

Comment: So if user selects "Rented", it will display only the "Rented" data. so on and so forth.

Comment: But the "all" data will be displayed at the start to show everything since its default

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, share where all that data comes from - do you use any database?

Comment: Yes i'm using phpadmin but i dont really wanna show because its gonna look really messy, i just wanna know how i can replace a set data after a submit button is clicked

Comment: You seem to have the logic right in your pseudo code. I think you need to clarify exactly what you're asking here. 
It seems like you want someone to help write the implementation of the query for a db schema that we don't know.

Comment: Maybe you want to use AJAX to replace the data? Is that what I am picking up on? It's not quite clear what you want to do.

Comment: I dont think i got the logic right, basically even after clicking on the submit button for any value(Available/Rented/Overdue), the page will still display the "all" data

Comment: @Ripytide ^ here u go

Comment: You don't need to "replace" any data that is not written yet. Simply add the neccessary logic to your query to filter for that condition. But until you add more details, it's impossible to tell you how to do this

Comment: @NicoHaase ok gimme a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP of the page edit it according to yourself:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit6"])) {
     if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {   
     if($_POST["status"] == "Available") {
         $servername = "localhost";
         $username = "username";
         $password = "password";
         $dbname = "myDB";

         $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
         if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
         }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {enter tablename remove the brackets as well} WHERE status='available'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       //edit this according to yourself.
   }
   } else {
   echo "0 results";
   }
   $conn->close();
     }
     }
 }
 ?>
```

It took me an hour to understand what you are actually trying to say at least write a few more details. This was not a fair game.